# CSS: Responsive left-hand menu, content in right-hand column?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive layout, with a left-hand sidebar that collapses on narrower screens. Something a bit like http://purecss.io/ but with a fixed top header as well.

My work so far (the code is really too long to reproduce here): http://jsbin.com/uhalic/3/edit

There are two problems that I'm struggling to fix (NB you'll need to make the HTML section wider than 450px to reproduce these):

(1) The last elements of the list are being shifted sideways, for no reason I can understand.

[image]

(2) The footer should be visually contained entirely within the `#main` (red section), and indeed that's where it is semantically, but the text is falling partly into the `#sidebar` (blue section).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the left sidebar to be sticky? I mean, Should it be all the time on the top even if you scroll? / edit: something like that? http://jsbin.com/uhalic/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the red column has no `<li>` elements to the left of it, so there are actually 4 `<li>` elements in the red section which are being skewed, two are to the left of each visible one but being hidden.

You need to add a `margin-left: 160px` to the `.results` class. Then remove the `width: 100%` off of the .result or if you're going to keep it, have it as 100%.

Also, add `margin-left: 200px` to `#footer`